# Accessing a database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, directory, terminal

I am running a MySQL database with Mac OS X Lion Server. I have a PHP script running on my server that wants to access a database. The PHP script is here:

/Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/Default

The database is here:

/usr/local/mysql

How do I get the PHP script to access the database if they are not in the same directory (the database is above it). Thanks for your help!

Here is the error I am experiencing:

```
Connect failed: No such file or directory?There seems to have been a  slight problem with our database, please try again later.<br /><br />? <textarea rows="10" cols="80">MySQL Error:???42??Error: ?Error #: ?  Filename:
```

And in my PHP file, this is the code I use to access the database:

```
$this->DB_HOST = '67.85.14.141';
$this->DB_USERNAME = 'username';
$this->DB_PASSWORD = 'password';
$this->DB_DATABASE = 'Carillons';
```

Rest of code below:

```
/**
 * Begin Document
 */

class DbConnect
{
/**
* Connection to MySQL.
*
* @var string
*/
var $link;

/**
* Holds the most recent connection.
*
* @var string
*/
var $recent_link = null;

/**
* Holds the contents of the most recent SQL query.
*
* @var string
*/
var $sql = '';

/**
* Holds the number of queries executed.
*
* @var integer
*/
var $query_count = 0;

/**
* The text of the most recent database error message.
*
* @var string
*/
var $error = '';

/**
* The error number of the most recent database error message.
*
* @var integer
*/
var $errno = '';

/**
* Do we currently have a lock in place?
*
* @var boolean
*/
var $is_locked = false;

/**
* Show errors? If set to true, the error message/sql is displayed.
*
* @var boolean
*/
var $show_errors = false;

/**
* Log errors? If set to true, the error message/sql is logged.
*
* @var boolean
*/
public $log_errors = false;

/**
* The Database.
*
* @var string
*/
public $DB_DATABASE;

/**
* The variable used to contain a singleton instance of the database connection.
*
* @var string
*/
static $instance;

/**
* The number of rows affected by the most recent query.
*
* @var string
*/
public $affected_rows;

public $insert_id;



/**
* Constructor. Initializes a database connection and selects our database.
*/
function __construct()
{
    $this->DB_HOST     = '67.85.14.141';
    $this->DB_USERNAME = 'username'; // !!! CHANGE ME
    $this->DB_PASSWORD = 'password'; // !!! CHANGE ME
    $this->DB_DATABASE = 'Carillons'; // !!! CHANGE ME
}

/**
* Singleton pattern to retrieve database connection.
*
* @return mixed MySQL database connection
*/
function _get($property)
{
    if(self::$instance == NULL)
    {
        self::$instance = $this->connect();
    }

    return self::$instance->$property;

}


/**
* Singleton pattern to retrieve database connection.
*
* @return mixed MySQL database connection
*/
function Connection()
{
    if(self::$instance == NULL)
    {
        self::$instance = $this->connect();
    }
    return self::$instance;
}


/**
* Connect to the Database.
*
*/
function connect()
{
    self::$instance = new mysqli($this->DB_HOST, $this->DB_USERNAME, $this->DB_PASSWORD, $this->DB_DATABASE);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        $this->raise_error(printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error()));
    }

    return self::$instance;
}


/**
* Executes a sql query. If optional $only_first is set to true, it will
* return the first row of the result as an array.
*
* @param  string  Query to run
* @param  bool    Return only the first row, as an array?
* @return mixed
*/
function query($sql, $only_first = false)
{
    if(self::$instance == NULL)
    {
        self::$instance = $this->connect();
    }

    $this->recent_link =& self::$instance;
    $this->sql =& $sql;

    if(!$result = self::$instance->query($sql))
    {
        $this->raise_error(printf("Connect failed: %s\n", self::$instance->error));
    }

    $this->affected_rows = self::$instance->affected_rows;
    $this->insert_id = self::$instance->insert_id;
    $this->query_count++;

    if ($only_first)
    {
        $return = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        $this->free_result($result);
        return $return;
    }
    return $result;
}

/**
* Fetches a row from a query result and returns the values from that row as an array.
*
* @param  string  The query result we are dealing with.
* @return array
*/
function fetch_array($result)
{
    return @mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
}

/**
* Returns the number of rows in a result set.
*
* @param  string  The query result we are dealing with.
* @return integer
*/
function num_rows($result)
{
    return self::$instance->num_rows;
}

/**
* Retuns the number of rows affected by the most recent query
*
* @return integer
*/
function affected_rows()
{
    return self::$instance->affected_rows;
}


/**
* Returns the number of queries executed.
*
* @param  none
* @return integer
*/
function num_queries()
{
    return $this->query_count;
}

/**
* Lock database tables
*
* @param   array  Array of table => lock type
* @return  void
*/
function lock($tables)
{
    if (is_array($tables) AND count($tables))
    {
        $sql = '';

        foreach ($tables AS $name => $type)
        {
            $sql .= (!empty($sql) ? ', ' : '') . "$name $type";
        }

        $this->query("LOCK TABLES $sql");
        $this->is_locked = true;
    }
}

/**
* Unlock tables
*/
function unlock()
{
    if ($this->is_locked)
    {
        $this->query("UNLOCK TABLES");
    }
}

/**
* Returns the ID of the most recently inserted item in an auto_increment field
*
* @return  integer
*/
function insert_id()
{
    return self::$instance->insert_id;
}

/**
* Escapes a value to make it safe for using in queries.
*
* @param  string  Value to be escaped
* @param  bool    Do we need to escape this string for a LIKE statement?
* @return string
*/
function prepare($value, $do_like = false)
{
    if(self::$instance == NULL)
    {
        self::$instance = $this->connect();
    }

    if ($do_like)
    {
        $value = str_replace(array('%', '_'), array('\%', '\_'), $value);
    }

    return self::$instance->real_escape_string($value);
}

/**
* Frees memory associated with a query result.
*
* @param  string   The query result we are dealing with.
* @return boolean
*/
function free_result($result)
{
    return @mysql_free_result($result);
}

/**
* Turns database error reporting on
*/
function show_errors()
{
    $this->show_errors = true;
}

/**
* Turns database error reporting off
*/
function hide_errors()
{
    $this->show_errors = false;
}

/**
* Closes our connection to MySQL.
*
* @param  none
* @return boolean
*/
function close()
{
    $this->sql = '';
    return self::$instance->close();
}

/**
* Returns the MySQL error message.
*
* @param  none
* @return string
*/
function error()
{
    $this->error = (is_null($this->recent_link)) ? '' : self::$instance->error; 
    return $this->error;
}

/**
* Returns the MySQL error number.
*
* @param  none
* @return string
*/
function errno()
{
    $this->errno = (is_null($this->recent_link)) ? 0 : self::$instance->errno ;
    return $this->errno;
}

/**
* Gets the url/path of where we are when a MySQL error occurs.
*
* @access private
* @param  none
* @return string
*/
function _get_error_path()
{
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])
    {
        $errorpath = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    }
    else
    {
        if ($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'])
        {
            $errorpath = $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];
        }
        else
        {
            $errorpath = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
        }

        if ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])
        {
            $errorpath .= '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
        }
    }

    if (($pos = strpos($errorpath, '?')) !== false)
    {
        $errorpath = urldecode(substr($errorpath, 0, $pos)) . substr($errorpath, $pos);
    }
    else
    {
        $errorpath = urldecode($errorpath);
    }
    return $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $errorpath;
}

/**
* If there is a database error, the script will be stopped and an error message displayed.
*
* @param  string  The error message. If empty, one will be built with $this->sql.
* @return string
*/
function raise_error($error_message = '')
{
    if ($this->recent_link)
    {
        $this->error = $this->error($this->recent_link);
        $this->errno = $this->errno($this->recent_link);
    }

    if ($error_message == '')
    {
        $this->sql = "Error in SQL query:\n\n" . rtrim($this->sql) . ';';
        $error_message =& $this->sql;
    }
    else
    {
        $error_message = $error_message . ($this->sql != '' ? "\n\nSQL:" . rtrim($this->sql) . ';' : '');
    }

    $message = "<textarea rows=\"10\" cols=\"80\">MySQL Error:\n\n\n$error_message\n\nError: {$this->error}\nError #: {$this->errno}\nFilename: " . $this->_get_error_path() . "\n</textarea>";

    if (!$this->show_errors)
    {
        $message = "<!--\n\n$message\n\n-->";
    }
    else die("There seems to have been a slight problem with our database, please try again later.<br /><br />\n$message");
}
}

?>
```

Comment: where do u connect to the database...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL is not accessed based on files.

As long as it is running you just need the server name username and password to the mysql databse.

Comment: Ok, because this is all used in an app. When running the app, I get this return data. When converted, it says this: Connect failed: No such file or directory?There seems to have been a 
slight problem with our database, please try again later.<br /><br />? 
<textarea rows="10" cols="80">MySQL Error:???42??Error: ?Error #: ? 
Filename:

Comment: Sorry, hit enter by accident. It's above.

Comment: @Jack. please add the error to ur question.

Comment: can you post any PHP code? this doesn't really get far from the information your giving us... directories shouldn't be a problem as you connect via the local socket configured in php

Comment: Hi, I posted all of the code at this link: chillysky.com/code.txt. I can also give you access to the database, if you want. Nothing is in it, so I don't really care.

Comment: Ok, because I'm having trouble formatting it since it's long. Don't you put four spaces before each line?

Comment: Nm, got it posted above.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a java coder but mysql database is something you can connect to over the network wo any access to the local filesystem. basically you'd need the php library or module that talks to the mysql db which just might be a standard plugin. For java its a specific library called connector for j.

To get a connection to the db what Neal said is correct, you just need the hostname or ip, username, password, and database name. sometimes this is all combined into something called the database connection string.

Here's a link that might help as i'm not fluent in php:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

good luck!

Comment: you probably want to make sure the database server is set up correctly. you can use the mysql command line tool to long into a database locally to get an idea if the database server is running... mysql -u username -ppassword